# Dependency injection in a simple Spring application does not work (injection Service into Controller variable)

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, autowired, code-injection

I have a really simple project.

It has the main class:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

A controller:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping("/application")
    public String getApp(ModelMap model) {
        return "application";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/application/home")
    public String do(@RequestParam(value="input", required=false) String input, ModelMap model) {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(input)) {
            model.addAttribute(INPUT_ATT, input);
            model.addAttribute(OUTPUT_ATT, myService.do(input));
        }
        return "home";
    }

}
```

And a service (interface, implementation):

```
package com.example;

public interface MyService {

    String do(String input);
}
```

.

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Override
    public String do(String input) {
        return "result";
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, an instance of MyServiceImpl does not get injected to myService variable in controller class.

What should I do to solve that problem?

With regards,

Comment: You are developing spring mvc application. You need to initialize configuration class properly. Code in Application is not sufficient to make application work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not compiled since 'do' is a keyword. But other than that, your code should be fine. I also try with SpringBoot with slight modification

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    /**
     * Run the Web Application using built-in Tomcat server.
     * This is used for testing only
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class HelloworldController {

    @Autowired
    private IHelloworldHelper helper;

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public Helloworld hello(String name) {
        return new Helloworld(1, helper.doAction(name));
    }
}
```

Helper

```
@Service
public class HelloworldHelper implements IHelloworldHelper {

    @Override
    public String doAction(String name) {
        return String.format("Hi %s!", name);
    }
}

public interface IHelloworldHelper {

    public String doAction(String name);
}
```

Model

```
public class Helloworld {

    private long id;
    private String content;

    public Helloworld(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Application class should look something like below.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example" })
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }
//other configuration

}
```

and WebAppInitializer class which starts your application should be similar to this

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(ServiceConfig.class, JPAConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(MvcConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");    
    }   
 }
```

Comment: It is sufficient to annotate your Application Class with @Configuration.

Comment: @EnableWebMvc is equivalent to <mvc:annotation-driven /> in XML. It enables support for Controller-annotated classes that use annoted RequestMapping to map incoming requests to a certain method more http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config

Answer (score 0):

Add @ImportResource parameter as "spring application context xml path"

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("applicationContext.xml")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```